# Autofilling mathematically related properties in an entity

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, getter-setter

Let's say I have an object that represents an electrical circuit.

```
public class Circuit
{
  private int? resistance;
  private int? current;
  private int? voltage;
}
```

Given that `current = voltage/resistance` I can calculate the unknown property if I know the other two.

My first thought was that naturally the relationship between the properties should be built into the object. So that when setting any of the properties an unknown can be autofilled if the other two are known. This would work fine until a situation arises where all properties are set and one needs to be modified resulting in confusion over which of the other two properties should be modified to enforce the relationship. The other properties I suppose would need to be set to null at this point.

Is having setters with side effects like this viewed as acceptable practice? Are there other ways of enforcing such a relationship?

**Further info**

This is a simplified representation. The resistance could also be determined by inputting wire length and diameter and a resistance constant, I could also have wattage and phase. I am working in a databound scenario and have to persist the state of the object. As the number of properties increases and their relationship to one another gets more complex my setters get a little out of control.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the `current` property in the `resistance` or `voltage` setter. Instead simply calculate the value in the `current` getter.

```
public class Conductor
{
  private int? resistance;
  private int? current() { return voltage/resistance; }
  private int? voltage;
}
```

Comment: But what if I know current and voltage for one conductor instance, and resistance and current for another?

Comment: Refer to my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is that your assumption is wrong: A conductor in a circuit is not defined by its resistance, current and voltage, but only any two of them: The third one (regardless which) is implied by the values of the others. Therefore, you only need two attributes to describe a fully determined state of your conductor. Lets take `resistance` and `voltage` for simplicity. Then, to enforce the relationship between current and voltage, you could write:

```
public class Conductor
{
  private float resistance;
  private float voltage;

  public void setVoltage( float voltage )
  {
    this.voltage = voltage;
  }
  public float getVoltage()
  {
    return voltage;
  }

  public float getCurrent()
  {
    return getVoltage() / getResistance();
  }
  public void setCurrent( float current )
  {
    this.voltage = current * getResistance();
  }

  public void setResistance( float resistance )
  {
    this.resistance = resistance;
  }
  public void setResistance( float current, float voltage )
  {
    setResistance( voltage / current );
  }
  public float getResistance()
  {
    return resistance;
  }

}
```

For any further setters, such as setting the conductor's resistance based on wire length, diameter and a resistance constant, you won't require any new attributes (!) but only the setters themselves:

```
  public void setResistance( float constant, float diameter, float length )
  {
    this.resistance = constant * length / ( 2 * Math.PI * diameter * diameter );
  }
```

Same is true for further getters:

```
  public float getResistanceConstant( float diameter, float length )
  {
    return ( getResistance() * ( 2 * Math.PI * diameter * diamter ) ) / length;
  }
```

If you nevertheless need to store diameter as an attribute, you should derive a class `Wire` from `Conductor`, since not every conductor's resistance is defined by it's length, diameter and resistance constant, but only those of wires. But remember: Again, you won't need to store all the three values as arguments, but only two of them - the third one's value is already implicitly defined, since you got the resistance as an attribute.

Comment: And if resistance is my unknown?

Comment: Add a method that computes the resistance. I have edited my suggestion for this case.

Comment: I've added a few more methods. It should now fit your requirements.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology was wrong. I appreciate your answer. Question is updated.

Comment: I've edited my answer so it better meets your requirements now.